# How to use an ''if '' statement to make an condition while creating a table in plsql or is it possible to do the same in mysql?

Tags: mysql, types, conditional-statements, row

I want that the column could accept only Latin characters, how should I code? What do you suggest?

For example( in MySQL):

```sql
Create table employees_info(
employee_id int not null auto_increment,
first_name varchar(30) not null,
primary key(employee_id));

-- here I tried to use a 'check' clause but I  guess I could not use it correctly
```

I want that the column first_name could able to accept only Latin char;

Comment: *I tried to use a 'check' clause but I guess I could not use it correctly* Show your attempt.

Comment: `CHECK` is not meant to be used this way. You rather set CHARSET and COLLATION attributes and control input from your application layer.

Comment: check(first_name like ‘A-z’)